# Create combo box with values from a user defined function

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, vba

I found this user defined function to list all the tables within an access database from:  http://www.consultdmw.com/access-VBA-list-objects.htm

The user defined function is as follows:

```
Function dmwListAllTables() As String

Dim tbl As AccessObject, db As Object
Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Set db = Application.CurrentData
For Each tbl In db.AllTables
Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next tbl

strMsg = " -- Tables listing complete -- "

Procedure_Done:
dmwListAllTables = strMsg
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
strMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Procedure_Done

End Function
```

This function was originally designed to print all table names with in the current database to the immediate window, however  I am looking for a way to incorporate `dmwListAllTables()` outputs as the values used in a form with a combo box.  Is this feat possible?

Thanks in advance,

dubbbdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the code can be modified to do what you want. Just a question of at what point would you want this to happen. Does the ComboBox need to populate the names of tables when the form loads or when a button is clicked? All you have to do is something like, (for easier example I will use when the Form Loads),

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.comboBoxName.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Me.comboBoxName.RowSource = dmwListAllTables()
End Sub
```

Then your function to be modified as,

```
Function dmwListAllTables() As String
    Dim tbl As AccessObject, db As Object
    Dim strMsg As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set db = Application.CurrentData

    For Each tbl In db.AllTables
        strMsg = strMsg & tbl.Name & ";"
    Next tbl

Procedure_Done:
    dmwListAllTables = strMsg
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    strMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Procedure_Done
End Function
```